# Improving the site description on our take-a-tour page

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center, new-users

Our [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) page says:

> ## Welcome to Code Review Stack Exchange
>
> [CR http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codereview/img/apple-touch-icon.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codereview/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
>
> **Code Review** is a question and answer site for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review.
>   It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites.
>   With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed code reviews.

That wording has been in place since January 2013, and it just echoes the standard formulaic greeting used on most other Stack Exchange sites.

I don't think that the wording suits us.  How should be better summarize our mission to newcomers?

As examples of sites that deviate from the standard template, see [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour).

Comment: A related known issue: the [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/18302/9357) that is featured just below that is now historical-locked. I'm working to get that updated to a better example.

Comment: Related question: [Insufficient "How to ask"](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/insufficient-how-to-ask)

Comment: Are we going to change the question in the tour as well?

Comment: the site launched in January 2011, not 2013. Typo or is there a reason why you wrote 2013 ?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg You're right, my chronology is off. The edit history for the tour page says January 2013, for some reason.

Comment: I suppose the reason is that it actually was edited in January 2013? Or perhaps that is when SE changed the system, which made the analytical badge obsolete?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's focus on getting important ideals of the site across to potential new users. We expect the code to work, and we expect it to be yours to share.

> **Code Review** is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.
>   It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites.
>   We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.